# Binding PasswordBox Visibility по нажатию на Button

Tags: c#, wpf

Здраствуйте.

Вопрос в следующем, есть два поля PasswordBox1 PasswordBox2, кнопка Button1, как по mvvm осуществить аналог кода ниже?

public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

```
    {

        if (PasswordBox2.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden)

        {

            PasswordBox2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            PasswordBox3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }

        else

          {

                PasswordBox2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                PasswordBox3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            };

    }
```

Comment: Я бы не применял MVVM для этого. Видно пароль или нет — забота View, так как является всего лишь особенностью отображения данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <PasswordBox Width="200" 
                     Visibility="{Binding BoolValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"/>
        <PasswordBox Width="200" 
                     Visibility="{Binding BoolValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"/>
        <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="Click me" Command="{Binding Command}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Command = new DelegateCommand(() => BoolValue = !BoolValue);
        BoolValue = true;
    }

    private bool _boolValue;

    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return _boolValue; }
        set
        {
            _boolValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => BoolValue);
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand Command { get; set; }
}
```